# ruby match string or space/tab at the beginning of a line and insert uniq lines to a file

Tags: ruby

This is my code:

```
    File.open(file_name) do |file|
      file.each_line do |line|;
        if line =~ (/SAPK/) || (line =~ /^\t/ and tabs == true) || (line =~ /^ / and spaces == true)
        file = File.open("./1.log", "a"); puts "found a line #{line}"; file.write("#{line}".lstrip!)
        end
      end
    end

File.open("./2.log", "a") { |file| file.puts File.readlines("./1.log").uniq }
```

1. I want to to insert all the lines that match a specific string, start with tab or start with space to a file `1.log`, all lines should be with space/tab at the beginning so I removed them.
2. I want get the unique lines in `1.log` and write them to `2.log`
3. It will be great if some can go over the code and tell me if something is not correct.
4. When using files in Ruby, what is the difference between the `w+` and `a` modes?

I know:

> w+ - Create an empty file for both reading and writing.
>
> a - Append to a file.The file is created if it does not exist.

But both options append to the file, I though `w+` should behave like `>`, instead of `>>` ,so I guess `w+` also like >> ?

Thanks !!

Comment: As a note there's no need for `x == true`. If `x` is true, you can use `x` by itself. Likewise `"#{x}"` is wasteful. Just use `x`, as in `line.lstrip!`.

Comment: `tabs` and `spaces` are local variables that were initialized before executing the code your have shown, or they are methods.  Correct?

Comment: @CarySwoveland no I didn't define them, i am not sure from where ruby take them

Comment: In that case your code should raise an exception when each of those is referenced, since they are either uninitialized local variables or names of non-existent methods (e.g., NameError: undefined local variable or method 'tabs' for main:Object.).

Comment: new question `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39714009/ruby-tempfile-line-match-and-remove-duplicate-lines`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of confusion in this code and it isn't helped by your habit of jamming things on a single line for no reason. Do try and keep your code clean, as the functionality should be obvious. There's also a lot of quirky anti-patterns like stringifying strings and testing booleans vs booleans which you should really avoid doing.

One thing you'll want to do is employ [`Tempfile`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html) for those situations where you need an intermediate file.

Here's a reworked version that's cleaned up:

```
Tempfile.open do |temp|
  File.open(file_name) do |input|
    input.each_line do |line|
      if line.match(/SAPK/) || (line.match(/^\t/) and tabs) || (line.match(/^ /) and spaces)
        puts "found a line #{line}"

        temp.write(line.lstrip!)
      end
    end
  end

  File.open("./2.log", "w+") do |file|
    # Rewind the temporary file to read data back
    temp.rewind

    file.write(temp.readlines.uniq)
  end
end
```

Now `a` and `w+` are largely similar, it's just two ways that are offered for people familiar with whatever notation. It's like how Array has both `length` and `size` which do the same thing. Pick one and use it consistently or your code will be confusing.

My criticism over things like `x == true` is because something that narrowly specific usually means that `x` could take on a multitude of values and `true` is one particular case we're trying to handle, something that implies that we should be aware it might be `false` and many other things. It's a [red herring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring) and will only invite questions.

Comment: thank you very much, i could check your answer in couple of hours

Comment: hey @tadman, I got ` `block (2 levels) in <main>': undefined local variable or method `temp' for main:Object (NameError) `
on `temp.rewind`, do you know maybe why ?

Comment: I get the file names like this
`files = Dir["./files_tmp/*.log"]; files.each do |file_name|; puts file_name if !File.directory? file_name`

Comment: Make sure all references to `temp` are inside the block that defines it. If you've got another question including that code, by all means, post it, but that is a separate issue.

Comment: thanks its works! but with this solution I got kind of array in `./2.log` `["SAPK-60416INEA\n", ""SAPK-60416INEAA\n",....]`
I actually need something like I post, each match for example `SAPK-60416INEA` in a new line, can you please help with that?

Comment: That's a new issue, which is fine, but it should be addressed in a separate Stack Overflow question.

Comment: thanks, here is the new post :)
`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39714009/ruby-tempfile-file-write-result`

Comment: new question `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39714009/ruby-tempfile-line-match-and-remove-duplicate-lines`