# Ruby Tempfile - line match and remove duplicate lines

Tags: ruby

Further to stackoverflow question in the link below:

```
ruby match string or space/tab at the beginning of a line and insert uniq lines to a file
```

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39682330/ruby-match-string-or-space-tab-at-the-beginning-of-a-line-and-insert-uniq-lines)

I have this files - `./files_tmp/60416.log`:

```
AAAAAA555
AAAAAA555
BBBBBB
CCCCC
  AAAAAA434343
  AAAAAA434343
```

`./files_tmp/60417.log`

```
AAAAAA55544
AAAAAA55544
BBBBBB
CCCCC
  AAAAAA434343
  AAAAAA434343
```

I have this code:

```
files = Dir["./files_tmp/*.log"]
files.each do |file_name|
  puts file_name if !File.directory? file_name
     Tempfile.open do |temp|
      File.open(file_name) do |input|
        input.each_line do |line|
          if line.match(/AAAAAA/) || (line.match(/^\t/) and tabs)
          puts "found a line #{line}"
            temp.write(line.lstrip!)
              end
            end
          end
      File.open("./temp.log", "a") do |file|
        temp.rewind
        file.write(temp.readlines.uniq.join(""))
      end
    end
end
```

1. the result of `puts "found a line #{line}"` is below, but I expected it will print **only** the lines with `AAAAAA`

```js
./files_tmp/60416.log
found a line AAAAAA555
found a line AAAAAA555
found a line BBBBBB
found a line CCCCC
found a line   AAAAAA434343
found a line   AAAAAA434343
./files_tmp/60417.log
found a line AAAAAA55544
found a line AAAAAA55544
found a line BBBBBB
found a line CCCCC
found a line   AAAAAA434343
found a line   AAAAAA434343
```

2. I can see duplicate lines in the temp file `./temp.log` and not all the lines with the lines `AAAAAA`

```js
    AAAAAA434343
    AAAAAA434343
```

I expected to :

```js
AAAAAA555
AAAAAA434343
AAAAAA55544
```

And I wonder why ?

3. I am using `file.write(temp.readlines.uniq.join(""))` instead of `file.write(temp.readlines.uniq)` because the result will be :

   `["AAAAAA434343\n"]`
4. it will be great to understand `rewind` purpose, what is it for?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: `w` mode truncates the content of the file whereas  `a` does not. When you use `a`, it works, because you `rewind` the file, instead consider using `r` as in `File.open("./2.log", "r+")`. If you want to write an array as separate lines, just `join` the array with `\n` as the separator, as in `array.join("\n")`

Comment: @yeyo thanks, can you please write the full line how to do it?

Comment: @yeyo I want to write each result in a new line without the array and "", just like `SAPK-60416INEA`

Comment: `file.write(temp.readlines.uniq.join("\n"))` will write each element of the array in different lines. Without the quotes ("").

Comment: @yeyo when I do something like this
`File.open("./4.log", "a") do |file|; temp.rewind; file.write(temp.readlines.uniq.join("")); end` it gives all the result without uniq

Comment: That may have solved your problem, but I believe is not the correct way. Suppose `temp` points to a large file, say`10 GiB`, `temp.readlines` will consume precious resources of the computer. Make sure you'll not encounter a large file that cripple your system or use a system tool instead, like the `uniq` command, a very efficient program explicitly designed for this task.

Comment: @yeyo this way `File.open("./4.log", "a") do |file|; temp.rewind; file.write(temp.readlines.uniq.join("\n")); end` it gives me all the result without uniq and there is a space between each line, I think I need something else, the files should be small around 1900 text lines.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124248/discussion-between-yeyo-and-berlin).

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to mess with `Tempfile`. Just collect what you want and afterwards write everything into the destination file:

```
result = Dir["./files_tmp/*.log"].each_with_object([]) do |file_name, lines|
  next if File.directory? file_name # skip dirs

  File.readlines(file_name) do |line|
    next unless line =~ /AAAAAA/

    puts "found a line #{line}"
    lines |= [line.lstrip!] # append if and only it’s uniq
  end
end

File.write("./temp.log", result.join($/)) # join with OS-aware line sep
```

Comment: you right! I did the same thing without `Tempfile` as you can see in my last question `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39682330/ruby-match-string-or-space-tab-at-the-beginning-of-a-line-and-insert-uniq-lines`, but @tadman recommend me to do it with Tempfile, but I think better to do it without, like you.

Comment: If @tadman said it’s better to use `Tempfile`, I would definitely use a `Tempfile`. He is a person I would listen to.

Comment: ok! I will wait to @tadman answer to my question, thank you both !
anyway I tried your solution, but nothing appear on temp file.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I tried your soultion, but it doesn't print any line + nothing on temp.log, can you please check again?

Comment: I don’t need to check it again, this is a perfectly working solution.